# one-liner return for "if any of these is true return false"

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

If you have a function that checks 4 conditions (let's say `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`) and that if any one of them is `true` the function should return `false`.

It works if you write it like this:

```
  function is () {
  return (
          !A && !B && !C && !D
  )
}
```

However, in this case (correct me if I'm wrong) - all of the conditions will be checked **each time** (while it can be enough that for example `A` is `true` to stop and return `false`

You can simply reverse the functionality of the function and use `return (A || B || C ||D )`, but what if you want it to stay like that.

i.e., what I'm looking for is a one-liner `return` that is equivalent to:

```
if (a) return false;
if (b) return false;
if (c) return false;
if (d) return false;
return true;
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the answers and comments, it is wrong to assume that in the first example all of the conditions will be checked each time. Once one of them evaluates to `false` (which means that at least one of `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` is true, i.e. "not not-true") it will stop and return `false`.

Comment: `return !(A || B || C || D)` would be the most to-the-point short-circuiting version. Not sure why you wouldn't want that. You can't have your cake and eat it too, i.e. you can't have it "stay like this" and also want something short-circuiting and also a one-liner.

Comment: Your first block of code works exactly like what you say you're looking for.

Comment: @deceze why not? Isn't !a && !b also a short circuiting one liner?

Comment: @le_m Sure, that too, same thing. I chose *"not A or B or C ..."* because it expresses the intend better, but they work the same in the end.

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong about this :

> However, in this case (correct me if I'm wrong) - all of the
>   conditions will be checked **each time** (while it can be enough that for
>   example A is true to stop and return false

In the case of a `&&` the expression is evaluated as `false`as soon as one term is false

Here is an [excerpt of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) :

> **Short-circuit evaluation**
>
> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
>   for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - `false` **&&** anything is short-circuit evaluated to `false`.
> - `true` **||**
>     anything is short-circuit evaluated to `true`.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in another answers and comments you can of course rewrite your expression this way:

```
return !(A || B || C || D)
```

There still should be a short circuit evaluation so there should no signifiant performance improvement but the expression might look clearer to some. IMO it is more a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong about how it works. Boolean operators like && and || shortcircuit; as soon as the whole expression has a known value, they stop testing. So in the code provided, if `A` is `true`, then `!A` is `false`, and it's impossible for `false && <anything>` to be `true`, so it immediately stops testing.

Every programming language I know of uses short-circuiting in cases like these, and it's not just an efficiency hack, it's a guaranteed part of the language standard, so expressions to the right of a test know that the earlier test passed. Otherwise, in a language like C, a test like `if (p && p->someattr)` wouldn't be safe, because without short-circuiting, `p` could be `NULL` but it would still be dereferenced to test `p->someattr`.

For the record, should you need to test some huge number of values to see if any are truthy, and you have them stored as an `Array`, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check them. For example:

```
 var resultarray = ...;
 if (resultarray.some(Boolean)) {

 }
```

Or to simulate your case, where you're testing for all of them to be falsy:

```
 var resultarray = ...;
 if (!resultarray.some(Boolean)) {

 }
```

Both of these short-circuit as soon as the find a single truthy value. Similarly, [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) can be used to test that all entries satisfy a condition, rather than at least one, and it short-circuits when at least one falsy value is found.